# Laravel : Bind only primary entities to my session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4

Using `Laravel 5.4`

I have following entities in my app:

**Employees**, **Contractors**, **Clients**.

I have restfull routes for each like so:

```
/employees/1
/contractors/1
/clients/1
..
```

I have the need to get the current entity based on the routes, so i did the following in my RouteServiceProvider:

```
Route::bind('employee', function ($value) {
    $employee = Employee::findOrFail($value);
    session(['activeEntity' => $employee]);
    return $employee;
});

Route::bind('client', function ($value) {
    $client = Client::findOrFail($value);
    session(['activeEntity' => $client]);
    return $client;
});

Route::bind('contractor', function ($value) {
    $contractor = Contractor::findOrFail($value);
    session(['activeEntity' => $contractor]);
    return $contractor;
});
```

This works fine for all the top-level routes. But i also have following routes:

```
/clients/1/employees/1
```

in this case i would like the activeEntity to be **Client**, but currently the active entity in the session will be set to **Employee**

How would i prevent that from happening? And bind the correct entity to the session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to handle it via middleware. You may create `SetActiveEntityMiddleware` with `handle()` method like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($request->is('employees/*')) {
        $id = $request->route()->parameter('employee');

        $employee = Employee::findOrFail($id);

        session(['activeEntity' => $employee]);
    }

    if ($request->is('clients/*')) {
        $id = $request->route()->parameter('client');

        $client = Client::findOrFail($id);

        session(['activeEntity' => $client]);
    }

    if ($request->is('contractors/*')) {
        $id = $request->route()->parameter('contractor');

        $contractor = Contractor::findOrFail($id);

        session(['activeEntity' => $contractor]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Here is Laravel [Middleware Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

Comment: thank you for you response. This is a nice solution the only issue that creates for me is that i also have prefixed routes : admin/clients , admin/employees. But that would also be solvable with this i think.